# Centos 7 nginx php upgrading

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, centos7

My currently running website works great and it currently using php 5.4.45 FPM/FastCGI, however I would like to upgrade to php 5.5.9+ for an api documentation subdomain that has that php requirement. after searching and trying different things for about 4 hours now and getting the result with yum update that no packages are found I'm not sure what to do? if I view available packages they are there yet if I try to updates I have no updates available..am I doing something wrong?

ok i got it to install but now I have a bad gateway error and it still says Im using 5.4.45 even tho 5.5.31 installed

```
    Total                                               45 MB/s |  39 MB  00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : llvm-libs-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                                1/23
  Updating   : llvm-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                                     2/23
  Updating   : clang-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                                    3/23
  Installing : libzip-last-1.0.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64                         4/23
  Installing : php-pecl-zip-1.13.1-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64                   5/23

WARNING : These php-* RPMs are not official Fedora / Red Hat build and
overrides the official ones. Don't file bugs on Fedora Project nor Red Hat.

Use dedicated forum at http://forum.remirepo.net/

  Updating   : php-common-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                         6/23
warning: /etc/php.ini created as /etc/php.ini.rpmnew
  Installing : php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64                  7/23
  Updating   : php-pdo-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                            8/23
  Updating   : php-cli-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                            9/23
  Updating   : php-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                               10/23
  Installing : php-mysqlnd-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                       11/23
  Updating   : php-fpm-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                           12/23
warning: /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf created as /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.rpmnew
  Updating   : clang-devel-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                             13/23
  Cleanup    : php-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                                 14/23
  Cleanup    : php-cli-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             15/23
  Cleanup    : clang-devel-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                             16/23
  Erasing    : php-mysql-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                           17/23
  Cleanup    : php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             18/23
  Cleanup    : php-fpm-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             19/23
  Cleanup    : clang-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                                   20/23
  Cleanup    : php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                          21/23
  Cleanup    : llvm-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                                    22/23
  Cleanup    : llvm-libs-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                               23/23
  Verifying  : php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64                  1/23
  Verifying  : php-pdo-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                            2/23
  Verifying  : php-fpm-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                            3/23
  Verifying  : clang-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                                    4/23
  Verifying  : libzip-last-1.0.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64                         5/23
  Verifying  : php-mysqlnd-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                        6/23
  Verifying  : php-cli-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                            7/23
  Verifying  : php-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                8/23
  Verifying  : php-common-5.5.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64                         9/23
  Verifying  : php-pecl-zip-1.13.1-1.el7.remi.5.5.x86_64                  10/23
  Verifying  : clang-devel-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                             11/23
  Verifying  : llvm-libs-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                               12/23
  Verifying  : llvm-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64                                    13/23
  Verifying  : php-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                                 14/23
  Verifying  : clang-devel-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                             15/23
  Verifying  : llvm-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                                    16/23
  Verifying  : llvm-libs-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                               17/23
  Verifying  : php-cli-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             18/23
  Verifying  : php-mysql-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                           19/23
  Verifying  : clang-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64                                   20/23
  Verifying  : php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                          21/23
  Verifying  : php-fpm-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             22/23
  Verifying  : php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64                             23/23

Installed:
  php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi

Dependency Installed:
  libzip-last.x86_64 0:1.0.1-1.el7.remi
  php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.9-1.el7.remi.5.5
  php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.13.1-1.el7.remi.5.5

Updated:
  clang.x86_64 0:3.4.2-8.el7               clang-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.2-8.el7
  llvm.x86_64 0:3.4.2-8.el7                llvm-libs.x86_64 0:3.4.2-8.el7
  php.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi           php-cli.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi
  php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi    php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi
  php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.5.31-1.el7.remi

Replaced:
  php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1

Complete!
[root@ns369459 ~]# php -v
PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1682 but version 1683 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2015 18:48:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.18, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
[root@ns369459 ~]# service nginx restart
Restarting nginx (via systemctl):                          [  OK  ]
[root@ns369459 ~]# php -v
PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1682 but version 1683 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2015 18:48:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.18, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
[root@ns369459 ~]# reboot
```

Comment: Probably the PHP 5.5.9 packages have a different name from the php 5.4 packages, exactly to prevent people from accidentally upgrading to a different PHP release with `yum update`  ; you may need to do something something like `yum install php-5.5`. I'm not quite sure exactly what you need.  Do you want to have both the 5.4 and the 5.5 releases installed?

Comment: well i got it to update i think using yum --noplugins --enablerepo=epel update and now my servers broken bad gateway error,

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. When you use cut-and-paste for posting console output please  format it as "`code`"  That improves readability immensely.

Comment: I've been trying to figure how to do this formatting code thing forever here still don't understand it, i just press code and then paste and never works.

Comment: Paste, then select the pasted section with your mouse and select `code` , or start a line with four spaces and it will be code, or use one of the limited html tags and place your console output between `<pre> </pre>` :)

Comment: Please run `which php` as you were previously asked.

Comment: "Please run which php as you were previously asked" what?

Answer (score -2):

Install the repo's

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Remove any already installed package from the official repo's

```
yum remove php-*
```

Install the package from the external package

```
yum install php56w php56w-opcache php56w-fpm php56w-mysql
```

Then restart fpm.

Comment: did this and it installed version 5.6 of php but still says 5.4.45 when i do -v

Comment: Did you install from source ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean I setup this whole thing from google, I really have no idea what I'm doing I just need php 5.5.9+ and I cant get it lol

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/4e25987ef212288e330505da494c37f3.png  As you can see 5.6 is installed yet the website and terminal versions are 5.4 I don't understand the issue lol

Comment: follow where the binary is : "which php" then you will get some location /usr/bin/php do an ls to know where php is linked from. did you also "yum remove php-cli" ?

Comment: did you also "yum remove php-cli" im afraid to do that as it may break my website again and it's hard for me to fix it, would u mind opening a private chat with me for some questions if u have time? it wants to remove the 5.6 version i installed only https://i.gyazo.com/b0146b9223967d3e3c1643ea7c280690.png

Comment: try : yum remove php-cli --disablerepo=webtatic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34353/discussion-between-svenn-dhert-and-loveroflua).

Comment: FYI: problem solved by a big cleanup of manually installed version (built from sources), and clean installation of remi'repo RPM.